# How Hive Impala/Spark can be configured for multi tenancy?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, impala

Tried to find out  but not able to find answer when i think of the following .

It covers Spark,Impala,MR,Hive Multi tenancy . Scenarios given with Impala. I feel it can be applied to Spark also as both Impala/Spark are Memory hogging.

**Scenario 1**  Say we create a 10 Node Cluster with Multi tenancy for both MR,Hive and Impala  with 40% resource statically allocated  to Impala .  For impala to run we created the the cluster with 256 GB RAM  Data nodes .

**Issue is**  with this kind of configuration we are losing the Benefit of Low cost  Lower GB i.e. 32-40 GB RAM with 5-6 core nodes  which is one of the main selling point of MR/Hadoop for Scaling during processing of 100TBs of data at fraction of cost.

**Scenario 2** : Create a cluster with a mix of 256GB RAM and 32-40 GB RAM nodes

**Issue is**   in this case Impala will not run  as we can not direct as per my understanding Hive tables to be created in specific data nodes where we are running the  Impala daemons in the cluster .

**Scenario 3** : Create separate Clusters i.e.  No Multi tenancy . In those case we need to copy the Data from Hive to Impala cluster .

**Issue is** This becomes another incremental process/ETL layer.

**Similar  to the above scenario i feel it applies to spark**  as SPARK also needs large memory  to operate .

Can we say create a MR,HIVE,HBASE,Streaming Multi tenant cluster  & a separate Impala,Spark Multi tenant cluster ?

Comment: I have created a multi tenant cluster with hive based tables (using hybrid HDFS + S3) along with spark and impala. While I don't have the specs in front of me since it's been a few months, I found impala to generally perform well with I believe it was 16GB. Spark also did very well using YARN and memory was not a big issue. The data/task nodes were EC2 i3.2xlarge because of their great performance and value (re NVMes, aggressively priced). Does that help?

Comment: @Garren 16GB is too low but again it depends upon data volume for processing,concurrency and type of queries ?  can u share these 3 parameters approximately .  understand With Parquet , Partitioning  etc . actual data processing size comes down drastically.  curious to know. Thanks.

Comment: My cluster was working on tens of billions of records each about 70 columns wide, working one one or two queries concurrently in parquet format (~1GB each gz compressed file) and aggregations plus joins to smaller fact tables also in parquet format. Extensive joins to many other tables ranging from hundreds of millions of records to tiny tens of record tables. I think 16GB was my memory setting, but I don't remember with full confidence

Comment: @Garren Thanks . My understanding . if u had mentioned no of nodes would v been helpful. Still it is helpful.   Issue is u may hv billion of records but  what is the size of records and what portion of records u r really accessing .  I understand with parquet in 1 TB table may be u r actually accessing few GBs for a day partitioned or max Hundred GBs in Monthly calc . In my question i went for Extreme . I feel  100 nodes with 128GB RAM in a real life Prod enc with 10-12 core can handle anything under PB except SCD type 2 DIm,Facts and MDM.,CORE EDW

Comment: 17 node i32xl. Accessing over half the records and about 10-20 columns at a time

Comment: @Garren . Thanks. I think we can close this now . Respect from heart.  .  without collocation  still one can discuss  & that is stackoverflow. Thanks to everyone .  GOD BLESS. Hope we will interact further .

Comment: it is closed . With Garren input  i hv come to some conclusion .

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer based on my above collection of comments.

I have created a multi tenant cluster with hive based tables (using hybrid HDFS + S3) along with spark and impala. While I don't have the specs in front of me since it's been a few months, I found impala to generally perform well with I believe it was 16GB on tens of billions of records (dozens/hundreds of TB uncompressed), each about 70 columns wide, working on one or two queries concurrently in parquet format (~1GB each gz compressed file). The queries were aggregations plus joins to smaller fact tables which were also in parquet format. The joins often involved many other tables in one query ranging from hundreds of millions of records to tiny tens of record tables, usually accessing about 10-20 columns at a time and using about half the billions of records at a time. Spark also did very well using YARN and memory was not a big issue. The data/task nodes were 17 EC2 i3.2xlarge because of their great performance and value (re NVMes, aggressively priced).

One note I didn't make in my comments is that you *may* be able to oversubscribe the memory so that you can maximize performance of each tool by using the cluster's resources fully. Natural caution here that oversubscribing means a higher risk of problems if/when you actually try to use all those resources at once (see: airline overbooking).

Comment: I agree  @Garren . It is difficult to give answers to the extreme question i had put . But ur answer helps  as with  of 17 nodes , 16 GB, Parquet etc can support many environment .  It  is workable . One thing is killing me is that in real production ENV there r data mismatch etc  . Now we have very narrow  ,side , mixed DB queries  and support teams r firing . so concurrency takes over  and it may be narrow ,medium,large in range  aand can saturate the environment . Would like to hear from ur side..

Comment: So in prod you've got lots of concurrent queries from support teams on wide-ranging datasets, wide, narrow and everything in between; your concern is that such a workload will be untenable to manage. As per the "mixed DB queries" - if you're talking about integrating data from external sources (MySQL, Redshift, etc) with your cluster data, I would strongly recommend setting up syncing processes to keep copies of this data locally (or even in S3 in Parquet). The performance is much more reliable and optimal for most analytic use cases.

Comment: Great . It was a a very fruitful  communication . Thank u very much .  Hope we will  communicate and share experiences in near future .